# how to include specific Anaconda python package in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I downloaded and installed `GDAL` through Anaconda `Environments` button at the left hand side of home page. It works in Anaconda Jupyter Notebook.

Currently I did `from osgeo import ogr` in VSCode, and the terminal says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'`.

I wish to import it too in VSCode. Then how to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I create a virtual environment called `onda` in Anaconda and download GDAL in `onda`. The point is that you should select the environment where you install the package as your interpreter:

[image]

Here is the solution:

1.Add Anaconda to environment path, including:

> **---\Anaconda3\Scripts**
>
> **---\Anaconda3**

2.Activate conda in powershell, run powershell as administrator and type the command:

> 1.**conda install -n root -c pscondaenvs pscondaenvs**
>
> 2.**Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned**

3.In VS Code, use the command `conda activate env_name` to activate and enter the environment;

If you didn't create virtual environment, the package `gdal` was default installed in `base` environment, so use `conda activate base`. Try to run python file in Terminal again.